# Does rows exists in pivot table

Tags: django

Is there a cleaner way to check does all providers for item exists in pivot table?
eg. I have few items, if one of them has all given providers then method should return True otherwise False

```
for item in items:
    exists_count = 0
    for provider in providers:
        if ItemProviderConn.objects.filter(
                item_id=item.pk,
                provider_id=provider.pk,
        ):
            exists_count += 1
        else:
            break

    if exists_count == len(providers):
        return True

return False
```

Comment: Please add your models to the question

Comment: @IainShelvington - your are don't really need it, the schema you can see in question.

Comment: @MaximDanilov it's not clear from the question what constraints are on the `ItemProviderConn` model, if `item` and `provider` are unique together then the solution may be simpler than if not

Comment: I think it is a simple m2m from item to provider with through model ItemProviderConn. In ask they do a simple filter, without special where.

Answer (score 1):

of Course you can do it better:

1. I hope your `items` and `providers` are `querySets`.
2. if i right understand - you want to check, if all providers exists in any item.

in this case:

```
provider_ids = providers.values_list('pk', flat=True)
length_of_providers = len(provider_ids)

#1. get a filter for providers
queryset = items.filter(ItemProviderConn__provider_pk__in=provider_ids)

#2. count a providers_id's
queryset =queryset.annotate(providercount=Count('ItemProviderConn__provider_pk'))

#3. check if a count of providers_id => length_of_providers
queryset=queryset.filter(providercount__gte=length_of_providers)

#4. return True if any item has enough providers
return queryset.exists()
```

by the way - all work with item `queryset` i can do in line.